# Detect ajax code in javascript content

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

How can we detect, in the content of javascript code returned by the web server, the portion of code that allows  client  Web to make AJAX calls?
  In other words, I want to know if there are existing libraries that can return the URL contained in the javascript code returned by the web server to the Web client. The URL returned by the web server to web client will allow the web client to make Ajax calls to the web server.

Here is an example
in the javascript code returned by a web server to web client, there are the following lines:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/index.php?option=com_rechercheperso&view=recupeSecteur&format=raw',
        data: 'style='+value_style+'&type='+value_type,
        success: function(response){
        $('#secteur').html(response);}
    });
}
```

The question, is there a library that allows us to return the url ('/ index.php? Com_rechercheperso option = & view = & format = raw recupeSecteur') in analyzing the content of javascript code.

Thank you for your answers

Toufik

Comment: WHY do you post code as an image (especially one with a ton of useless whitespace)?! Please post it as code and use the appropriate markdown to format it properly (4 space indent, or select it and press ctrl+k)

Comment: can you replace the image with actual code?

Comment: @ThiefMaster holy crap, `ctrl+k`! Can't believe I didn't know about that, I'd been managing my code formatting in a separate editor this whole time.

Answer (score 0):

From the description I assume, that the Server is handing back a page, in which there are scripts using ajax calls with predefined urls, and you want to get those urls.

If right, you could use any language to call that page which loads the scripts (php, perl or even a JS ajax), and search with a regexp for all the urls in the responseText, and then try the matching ones for forther ajax calls against the Server.

Looks like brute-force solution, but should work.